# MySQL heavy result read / write

Tags: mysql, locking

I have this lottery game in PHP. It is very simple, it consists of three tables:

```
awards:
 - ID
 - award_name

wingames:
 - ID
 - ID_award

allgames:
 - ID_user
 - won_game (bool)
 - award_id (if game not won, then it is 0)
```

It is announced, that at e.g. 18:00 pm the game starts. About 100 users are constantly clicking on "TRY TO WIN". Admin sometimes insert an award id into table wingames so next clicking user wins this item.

This button does this:
select id_award from wingames limit 1;
- if there are no rows - user lose the game, this query is made:
insert into allgames (id_user,won_game,award_id) values (43,false,0);
- if there is one row - user wins the game and software makes these two queries:
insert into allgames (id_user,won_game,award_id) values (43,true,5);
delete from wingames;

There is one problem: Until the "delete from wingames" query executes, another user reads from that table, that there is an award for him. So when 2 users click on the button in the same time, it may occur (and it already did), that there are two winners instead of one. And that is great problem, because i have to give two prizes instead of one.

I have looked on the internet for some "lock table" workaround but didnt find a suitable example.

Do you have any (maybe quick and dirty) solution?

Comment: Read about `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`

Comment: As an additional preventive measure to the [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), you can restrict field `award_id` in table `allgames` to **unique** so it prevents users from having the same `award_id`, therefore you only have to give 1 prize for each award.

Comment: thanks, good idea but it is possible to win the same price ... for example i have two mobile phones to give, so i give one at 18:30 and the second one at 18:45 ... the phones have the same award id. I have 9 different awards.

Answer (score 0):

As zerkms mentioned, you need SELECT .. FOR UPDATE. It will lock the games until the end of your transaction.

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT * FROM wingames FOR UPDATE;
/* from now on, only one request can continue, the others are blocked */

INSERT INTO allgames ...

DELETE FROM wingames WHERE ID = ...

COMMIT;
```

You should try this on two interactive clients to see how the FOR UPDATE statement works.

Comment: how to do it in php?
i mean like ... in separate queries?

mysql_query("start transaction;")
mysql_query("select....

doesn't it matter that i have only one db connection?

Comment: Yes, one connection per transaction.

Comment: Well I tried this. Improved results but the problem occured once - i had two winners on one item. Still better than 2 winners on every item, but didn't solve my problem. Any suggestions?